# r + Search string and return values

Tags: regex, r

This is pretty basic but I haven't found a simple way to do it. Say I have the following dataframe:

```
chars <- data.frame(type = c('ferrari_car--sport','ducati:bike:speed','honda:car_family','ninja_bike:speed','lambo_car','harley_bike'))
```

All I want is to search each of the values in the "type" column of this dataframe and create another column. If the text contains "car" then return "car"; if it contains "bike" then return "motorcycle" (ultimately I want to be able to do this for a bunch of different values)

My approach has been to duplicate the column, gsub "//car//" for "car" (and likewise for bike), then strip the "//" from either end.

Is there a faster/simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typestr <- c('ferrari_car','ducati_bike',
  'honda:trolley_family','ninja_bike:speed','lambo_car','harley_bike')

library(stringr)
xstr <- str_extract(typestr,"(trolley|car|bike)")
rstr <- list(c("car","car"),c("bike","motorcycle"),c("trolley","trike"))
for (r in rstr) xstr <- gsub(r[1],r[2],xstr)
```

or

```
ifelse(grepl("bike",typestr),"motorcycle",
     ifelse(grepl("car",typestr),"car",
           ifelse(grepl("trolley",typestr),"trike",NA)))
```

There might be alternatives with `str_replace`, or making the examples above more elegant with `Reduce()` ...

Comment: Awesome, thanks Ben. Can you explain the syntax a little bit fo rthe first option, with gsub and str_extract? If my dataframe was chars <- data.frame(type = c('ferrari_car','ducati_bike','honda:trolley_family','ninja_bike:speed','lambo_car','harley_bike')) and I also want to replace "trolley" with "trike"... how do I use the syntax you provided? adding it as a third argument in gsub and str_extract just makes everything "trike"